# Following and Rotating about a path in OpenGL

Tags: java, opengl, rotation, jogl

I'm attempting an exercise where a vehicle is following the [Lemniscate of Bernoulli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemniscate_of_Bernoulli) (or more simply, a figure-8 track).  I want to use `glTranslatef` and `glRotatef` to achieve this.  So far, I have been able to successfully get the vehicle to follow/translate along this path by using the parametric form as follows:

> X = (width * cos(t)) / (1+sin^2(t))
>   Y = (width * cos(t) * sin(t)) / (1+sin^2(t))
>   Where t is in -pi, pi

In the code, this is as follows:

```
carX = (float) ((Math.cos(t) / (1 + Math.sin(t)*Math.sin(t))));
carY = 0.0f;
carZ = (float) ((Math.cos(t) * (Math.sin(t))) / (1 + Math.sin(t)*Math.sin(t)));
gl.glTranslatef(carX,carY,carZ);
```

So that works well enough.  My problem now is rotating the vehicle so that it follows the path defined by the Lemniscate of Bernoulli.  I want to achieve this by using `glRotatef` to rotate around the Y axis, but I am not sure how to proceed in regards to finding the angle to input in `glRotatef`.  The rotate is currently in place so that it only manipulates the vehicle, and appears to just need the correct mathematics to follow the path.

Things I have tried:

- Using the derivative of the X and Y forms listed above.  I used them independently of each other, because I'm not sure how to/if they need to be combined to be used for the angle.  With some
  minor manipulation they follow the straight areas near the origin,
  but broke down around the curves.
- Directly finding the tangent of the
  t value and converting to degrees.  Erratic spinning resulted.

If anyone has any suggestions that may be better than the glRotatef method, that would be appreciated as well.  I've seen that `gluLookAt` [may be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384155/rotating-towards-path-in-opengl), and I may attempt to find a solution using that.

*(Note: I'm working in JOGL using Java and the FFP, but I'm comfortable with C/C++ code snippets.)*

Comment: Could you do something simpler like calculate `(carX(t+epsilon), carZ(t+epsilon))`, and use the vector from `(carX(t), carZ(t))` to it for the direction. Once you have that vector, the angle would be `Math.atan2(deltaZ, deltaX)`.

Comment: atan2(dy/dt, dx/dt) should give you the desired angle. Can you explain more what problems you are having with this approach?

Comment: Thanks to you both for the comments.  As best I can describe it, the vehicle currently rotates perpendicular to the blue line at the red point [in this example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Lemniscate_of_Bernoulli.gif).  After reading some more, that may actually be how it is suppose to be drawn for this example, although it isn't my desired behavior.  I'm away from my computer at the moment so I can't follow up on new attempts, but I'll update again if I find out anything new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming camera view is the driver's view, `gluLookAt` is exactly what you need! based on your `carX,carY,carZ` computations (assuming that the math is good), you can store previous values and use it:

```
//globals & imports:
import javax.vecmath.*;

Vector3f current = new Vector3f();
Vector3f prev = new Vector3f();
```

computation is as followed:

```
//on drawing:
prev.set(current);
current.x = (float) ((Math.cos(t) / (1 + Math.sin(t)*Math.sin(t))));
current.z = (float) ((Math.cos(t) * (Math.sin(t))) / (1 + Math.sin(t)*Math.sin(t)));

glu.gluLookAt(current.x, 0f, current.z,
              current.x - prev.x, 0f, current.z - prev.z,
              0f, 1f, 0f);
```

i'll test it when i get back home, to make sure it's working, but as far as i can tell, this should do the trick.